# How to test Typescript class members in React with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a Typescript class (with react) with public and private member functions.

```
export class Myclass {
    private itemList: SomeItem[];

    constructor(params) {

    }

    public method1() {

    }

    private method2() {

    }
}
```

How can I test method1 and method2 in my code using jest. I can do it for functions who are exported and are not members of a class. But how can I do it for class members.

Comment: public method should be available to you upon initiation in your test

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an instance...

```js
const instance = new MyClass()
```

---

Then, you can test `method1` by calling it directly...

```js
expect(instance.method1()).toBe(...)
```

---

For `method2`, you've got 3 options...

Use @ts-ignore:

```js
// @ts-ignore
expect(instance.method2()).toBe(...)
```

Cast as any:

```js
expect((instance as any).method2()).toBe(...)

// no type safety on method2
```

Change to `protected` and extend:

```js
class MyClass {
  protected method2() {}
}

class MyClassTester extends MyClass {
  public runTests() {
    expect(this.method2()).toBe(...)
  }

  // OR

  public method2Accessor(...args: any[]) {
    return this.method2(...args)
  }
}

const instance = new MyClassTester()

instance.runTests()

// OR

expect(instance.method2Accessor()).toBe(...)

// fully type-safe
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the class and then call its public methods in your test. There is no way around it.